# iPhone App Reading Data from Sqlite3 Database

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am using the following code to read the rows from the Sqlite3 database.

```
if(sqlite3_open([[AppHelper getDatabasePath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sqlStatement = "select * from customers";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement; 

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
        {
            NSString *firstName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];

            NSLog(@"%@",firstName);
        }
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement); 
}

sqlite3_close(database);
```

The code does not go into the `if(sqlite3_prepare_v2 ....`. condition.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I have the .sql file placed in my Documents Directory and it contains one record.

UPDATE 1:

I am running the app in the simulator and I placed my myDatabase.sql file inside the Supporting Files folder.

UPDATE 2:

The error is "No such table customers" but I can see that I have customers table in the database. I used FireFox Sqlite Manager to see the customers table.

Comment: I'd check the return code of sqlite3_prepare_v2. That should give a hint about what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Tom. I printed the RETURN CODE and it is 1. What does 1 mean?

Comment: 1 means SQL error or missing database.

Comment: Hmm the path is printing Documents folder but I do not have Documents folder. I have Supported Files folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to close/reset the simulator since the simulator was hanging on to the empty database. Once the simulator content was reset everyone started working again!

Comment: If you intend on writing to this database you absolutely have to copy the database from the resources folder to the user's Documents directory.  Otherwise you'll have troubles writing to the db.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, Yeah, when you change sqlite file, you always need to remove app and install again. Or if you want upgrade for new table, either you "Alter Table" old file or move all data to new file.